# Duplicate tags [meta] and [meta-tags]

Tags: support, synonym-request

[meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) and [meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags) are both about HTML `meta` elements. The latter is used a bit more often. I think both names are not that good, I'd rather like `html-meta`.

Comment: This is just so I can later say »I wrote on meta about the tags meta and meta-tags«.

Comment: [This question using both tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003326) has brought me to this meta post. Is there any progress with burninating or synonymizing?

Answer (score 1):

I would just burn the hell out of all those tags. The history of html elements tags has been very unsuccessful. Most users would just add the tag because their markup has it, not because they have a specific problem using the element. Just check the history of div, a, span, etc., you will be scared.